# How to get path to project-file inside iOS-project?

Tags: ios, swift, csv

If I add a CSV file into my iOS-project. How can I reference that file as the path, for a CSVReader to find the file?

At the moment I just drag the file into the Project-Folder in Xcode. The file is there, but then I need to tell the InputStream(fileAtPath: "/path/to/file.csv")!

How can I tell the InputStream where that path is? Earlier for the simulator I just used the file-path in computer. But that won't work when I try on a physical device of course.

Any suggestions?

Code:

```
        // Get file
        let stream = InputStream(fileAtPath: "file.csv")!  // Error since no idea where to look for file!
        let csv = try! CSVReader(stream: stream)
        while let row = csv.next(){

        // Handle results
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in the application bundle it's located in the `Resources` folder.

You have to ask `Bundle` for its URL (file paths are discouraged nowadays).

```
let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file", withExtension: "csv")!
let stream = InputStream(url: fileURL)!
```

Comment: Thank you bro! Is it any big difference between my solution EDIT in top-post and your solution more than that it's url/path?

Comment: Practically there is no difference. However as I said you are encouraged to prefer the URL related API over paths because `URL` contains all URL component APIs